# How to establish a database connection using Netbeans IDE on Mac?

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, xampp, connection

I have a DBConnection class and this is the code it contains,
package PremierLeague;

```
import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * @author leojoe
 */
public class DBConnection {

//create a function to connect to the DB
    
public Connection con;

public DBConnection() {
    
    //stage 1: Load Driver
    
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Diver loaded successfully");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println("Error: Could not load driver: " + cnfe.getMessage()) ;
    }
    
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/Players", "root", null);
        System.out.println("Connected successfully");
    }catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to the databse : " + sqle.getMessage());
    }
        }
    
//Establish Connection

}
```

and a DBOperations class, which I am using for the functions,
package PremierLeague;

```
public void selectOperation(String playerName) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;

    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBOperations {
    private Connection con; // Store the DBConnection instance in a private field

    // Constructor to receive the DBConnection instance
    public DBOperations(DBConnection dbConnection) {
        this.con = dbConnection.con;
    }

    public void insertOperation(String playerName, String clubName, String position, int shirt, char gender, float weight, float height, boolean isFit) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;

        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Players (playerName, clubName, position, shirt, gender, weight, height, isFit) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            pst.setString(1, playerName);
            pst.setString(2, clubName);
            pst.setString(3, position);
            pst.setInt(4, shirt);
            pst.setString(5, String.valueOf(gender));
            pst.setFloat(6, weight);
            pst.setFloat(7, height);
            pst.setBoolean(8, isFit);

            int rowsAffected = pst.executeUpdate();

            if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                System.out.println("Data inserted successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Insert operation failed.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("Insert operation failed: " + sqle.getMessage());
        }
    }    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Players WHERE playerName = ?";

        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
            pst.setString(1, playerName);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Player Name: " + rs.getString("playerName"));
                System.out.println("Club Name: " + rs.getString("clubName"));
                System.out.println("Position: " + rs.getString("position"));
                System.out.println("Shirt Number: " + rs.getInt("shirt"));
                System.out.println("Gender: " + rs.getString("gender"));
                System.out.println("Weight: " + rs.getFloat("weight") + " kg");
                System.out.println("Height: " + rs.getFloat("height") + " inches");
                System.out.println("Is Fit: " + (rs.getBoolean("isFit") ? "Yes" : "No"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("Select operation failed: " + sqle.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void updateOperation(String playerName, String newClubName) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;

        String updateQuery = "UPDATE Players SET clubName = ? WHERE playerName = ?";

        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
            pst.setString(1, newClubName);
            pst.setString(2, playerName);

            int rowsAffected = pst.executeUpdate();

            if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                System.out.println("Data updated successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Update operation failed. Player not found.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("Update operation failed: " + sqle.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void deleteOperation(String playerName) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;

        String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Players WHERE playerName = ?";

        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
            pst.setString(1, playerName);

            int rowsAffected = pst.executeUpdate();

            if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                System.out.println("Data deleted successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Delete operation failed. Player not found.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("Delete operation failed: " + sqle.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the main class as well,
package PremierLeague;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an instance of DBConnection to establish the database connection
        DBConnection dbc = new DBConnection();
        
        // Create an instance of DBOperations and pass the DBConnection object to it
        DBOperations dbo = new DBOperations(dbc); // Pass the DBConnection object to the constructor

        // Now you have a connection to the database in dbConnection.con.
        // You can use this connection to execute SQL queries or other database operations.

        String playerName = "John Doe";
        String clubName = "Sample Club";
        String position = "Forward";
        int shirt = 10;
        char gender = 'M';
        float weight = 75.5f;
        float height = 180.0f;
        boolean isFit = true;

        // Insert operation
        dbo.insertOperation(playerName, clubName, position, shirt, gender, weight, height, isFit);
        
        System.out.println("\n");
        
        // Select operation
        dbo.selectOperation(playerName);
        
        System.out.println("\n");
        
        // Update operation
        String newClubName = "New Club";
        dbo.updateOperation(playerName, newClubName);
        
        System.out.println("\n");
        
        // Delete operation
        dbo.deleteOperation(playerName);
    }
}
```

all this inside a package called Premier League, I have already created the table on MySQL and I am using XAMPP to run the servers,I have already configured the port, downloaded the jar file that I should import, and done so.

I expected a successful connection to the database, but when I run the code in the main class, these are the errors I get;
Error: Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Could not connect to the databse : No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/Players
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "this.con" is null

Comment: You sure you added the JDBC Driver? If so could you update by providing it's Version and your Java Version?

Comment: @Lytrix Hello, thank you for your response. The JDK version I am using is 20.0.2. And yes I am sure I added the driver. I downloaded the platform independent one, version 8.1.0 and added it. Let me know if you require any additional info/screenshots..etc